# How do I remove tags from my Tumblr theme?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I am using the "Optica" theme on Tumblr and I was wondering how I could remove the tags on my page. I don't like it showing the tags underneath each post; can I get rid of them? I tried deleting the code below, but it didn't work as none of the posts are showing anymore.

```
 {block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
   <li>
   <a href="{TagURL}" class="tag">{Tag}</a>
   </li>
   {/block:Tags}
 {/block:HasTags}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

What you were trying to do (deleting the `{block:HasTags} ... {/block:HasTags}` stuff) should actually have worked.. I recently had to *add* those to my own theme, since tags weren't being shown. Might be worth trying again, making sure not to change anything else? There might also be multiple places where that shows up and you'd need to delete them all.

---

#### Option 2

I don't think I'd recommend @Gabrielle Martin's answer the way it currently looks, since it could also hide where you reblogged something from. If you were going to try it, though, find the first place you see either `<style>` or `<style type="text/css">` and add what she suggested right after that.

---

#### Option 3

Another thing you could try would be adding a bit of *inline CSS*. Anywhere you see this:

```
 {block:Tags}
    <li>
```

You want to change it to this:

```
 {block:Tags}
    <li style="display:none;">
```

Ignore the `</li>`s, they're fine as-is.

Answer (score -1):

Search towards the bottom find where it has the =tags 
do not change simply remove all the tag coded area and it will automatically be removed from the page